# Preventing caption stoppers from appearing in references in ConTeXt

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, context

I would like to prevent caption stoppers from appearing in references in ConTeXt.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\starttext
\setupcaptions[numberstopper=.~---~, distance=0em]
\placefigure[][cow]{A Cow}{\externalfigure[cow]}
\in{Figure}[cow] shows a cow.
\stoptext
```

How can I remove that `numberstopper` from the `\in` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `suffix` instead of `numberstopper`.

```
\useMPlibrary[dum] % For dummy figures

\setupcaptions[suffix=.~---~, distance=0em]
\starttext
\placefigure[][cow]{A Cow}{\externalfigure[cow]}
\in{Figure}[cow] shows a cow.
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you Aditya, it works.
However, suffixes are not made for that so this trick may have side effects. I suggest we ask Mr Hagens to add a command for controlling the layout of numbers in references.